# Error in uploading file in S3 using boto 3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to upload a file in S3 using boto3.I tried below code.

```
 import boto3
 s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
 buck_name = s3.create_bucket(Bucket='trubuckboto')

s3.Object('trubuckboto','tlearn.txt').upload_file(
      Filename='G:\tlearn.txt')
```

My bucket creation is successfull but i am not able to upload file from location G:\tlearn.txt inside that bucket.Below is the error i am getting

return os.stat(filename).st_size
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'G:\tlearn.txt'

Can someone suggest what i am missing here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python strings, the backslash "\" is a special character, also called the "escape" character. If you want a literal backslash then you need to escape the escape character, for example `G:\\tlearn.txt`:

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
# buck_name = s3.create_bucket(Bucket='trubuckboto')

s3.Object('trubuckboto', 'tlearn.txt').upload_file(
    Filename='G:\\tlearn.txt')
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try this in evening and will update you.